# Is it permitted to change my name?

Tags: names

My first name is Amwaj. As I came to know that Amwaj is a female name, and I'm a male. I have following questions:

1. Is the name Amwaj a female name?
2. If it is a female name, should I change it?
3. Presently I'm only named Amwaj with o surname. Can I add my father's name to it without adding ibn (e.g., Amwaj Abdul Aziz instead of Amwaj ibn Abdul Aziz)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about [suitable names](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3035/) are not directly related to Islam.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer: *Is it permitted to change my name?*

In general, it's permissible to change one's name.  In fact, there's ahadith which encourages changing one's name to a better name, such as:

> Narrated Abu Huraira:  Zainab's original name was "Barrah," but it was said "By that she is giving herself the prestige of piety." So the Prophet changed her name to Zainab.
> <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 6192](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/216)</sub>
>
> Narrated Sa`id bin Al-Musaiyab:  That when his grandfather, Hazn visited the Prophet the Prophet said (to him), "What is your name?" He said, "My name is Hazn." The Prophet said, " But you are Sahl." He said, "I will not change my name with which my father named me." Ibn Al-Musaiyab added: So we have had roughness (in character) ever since.
> <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 6193](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/217)</sub>

This likely also applies to having a feminine name when you're a man:

> The Messenger of Allah cursed the women who imitate men and the men who imitate women.
> <sub>[Jami` at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/urn/630070) [grade: sahih]</sub>

There's exceptions, such as changing one's name to something un-Islamic.  Also, Islam teaches to respect one's family, which should be kept in mind when choosing a name.